# Chef cookbook completion tag to a log

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I’m running a standardisation cookbook as part of provision , I wanted to calculate the time taken to complete the entire server provision , how can we flag the date and time to a log when the standardisation completes

Server_installed_date standarization_date to /var/log/syslog